# Where are the chatrooms?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I clicked on the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=stellar.stackexchange.com) link and it took me to the chatrooms connected to the site of my parent account for chat instead of the Stellar.SE chatrooms also, I can't find the Stellar.SE main chatroom anywhere either.

**Update:** *The rooms are here now.*